# How can I put an $ionicModal to use it from a .factory?

Tags: angularjs

I know that from a .factory I can not use the `$scope`. How can I do to open the popup from a controller?

In my controller I need:

```
testigosElectoralesApp.controller('almacenarFotoController', function($scope,popup) {
 poupup.openModalAlmacenamientoErroneo ()
})
```

This is my code

```
factory("poupup", function($ionicModal,$rootScope) 
{
 var oPopup = {}

 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/almacenamientoErroneo.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.modalAlmacenamientoErroneo = modal;
});
$scope.openModalAlmacenamientoErroneo = function() {
  $scope.modalAlmacenamientoErroneo.show();
};
$scope.closeModalAlmacenamientoErroneo = function() {
  $scope.modalAlmacenamientoErroneo.hide();
};

 return oPopup;
})
```

I do not know how to fix this code to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would not want to call the scope inside a service/factory. But if you really want to, you can add $rootScope to service/factory and the controller. then use $rootScope.$emit or $rootScope.$broadcast in the service/factory.

In the controller where the $scope exists, you can add:

```
$rootScope.$on('scopeFunction', function () {
     $scope.something();
});
```

In the service/factory, you can then call:

```
$rootScope.$emit('scopeFunction');
```

or

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('scopeFunction');
```

OR you can store the item in the $rootScope. Though I would recommend not to overuse $rootScope.

*******************EDIT*****************

To be able to use this:

```
testigosElectoralesApp.controller('almacenarFotoController', function($scope,popup) {
 poupup.openModalAlmacenamientoErroneo();
})
```

You need this:

```
factory("poupup", function($ionicModal,$rootScope) {
    var oPopup = {
        openModalAlmacenamientoErroneo: function(){
            //Add function here
        }
    };
    return oPopup;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand. I want to have it in my factory and call it in any controller.

Comment: I;m sorry, I misunderstood. I edited my answer. Please check it and see if it helps.

Comment: thank you friend, but I would be in the same problem, I can not use the scope, I think I already tried something with $ rootScope and it did not work

Comment: is there any reason as to why you are using a factory for this? Have you thought of maybe using a directive instead?